# Add digital signature to byte array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, digital-signature

I want to read a text file (.txt) into a byte array and add a digital signature to said byte array. I then want to be able to verify this digital signature in my WCF service.

How does one accomplish this? Is it possible to add the digital signature to the text file before converting it to a byte array?

Would it perhaps be easier to use a pdf file instead or?

Comment: The .NET documentation has a [section on Cryptographic Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk8wx38z(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Your question is too broad in its current form.

Comment: I have resorted to using a XML file instead of a text file.